# How do I upgrade my Dell Inspiron Mini Duo's Intel processor?

Tags: dell-inspiron, intel-graphics

Recently, I have been thinking about upgrading a hand-me-down Dell Inspiron Mini Duo's Intel Atom processor to a more recent model before I start using it again. How can I do this?

Comment: If it is soldered in, as most CPU chips are soldered in, you cannot upgrade it.

Answer (score 0):

It is more than likely soldered onto the motherboard. I have read the model 1090 Inspiron Mini Duel, it only show's how to replace the motherboard. 

[direct download (.pdf)](https://downloads.dell.com/Manuals/all-products/esuprt_laptop/esuprt_inspiron_laptop/inspiron-duo_service%20manual_en-us.pdf)

This is the search (link) option I used https://www.dell.com/support/search/us/en/04#q=Inspiron%20Mini%20Duo&sort=relevancy&f:langFacet=[en]